# Why does my long integer change a tiny bit?

Tags: java, php, sql, rounding, long-integer

In my Java servlet, I generate a 64 bit integer every time a certain request is made. I then send this long in two directions:

1) as a JSON-encoded reply to the HTTP Get caller

2) into a MySQL database via a PHP script

1) Works like this: the number gets added to an ArrayList (via Long.toString()). This list is then converted to a JSON string via the Gson library. It then gets printed with the HTTP response's printwriter.

2) runs a PHP script with the long parameter passed as a command line parameter. This parameter is then read and fed into an SQL INSERT INTO query.

In the end, these two numbers differ by a little. In the last example, I get the following:

1) -753774083758266880

2) -753774083758266887

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you debugged the various steps? When does it change?

Comment: Could you determine where exactly the alteration occurs?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to debug this properly. Will hopefully have something set up soon.

Comment: Also, is there some JavaScript involved somewhere? JavaScript cannot handle `long`s properly... (this is why in my demo site for JSON Schema, I make JavaScript send _and_ display JSON as a strinng!)

Comment: No Javascript involved.

Comment: Okay I now know where the change happens. In path 1, when I try to retrieve the value from the JSONArray, something gets messed up. The toString() of the JSONArray looks like expected, but when I do a .getLong(0) on the object (the long is stored in position 0), a value that is slightly off gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but it is too long for a comment.

MySQL says that the `bigint` supports values from `-9223372036854775808`.

However, the following code on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/14254):

```
select cast('-753774083758266880' as signed),
       cast('-753774083758266887' as signed),
       cast('-9223372036854775807' as signed)
```

Returns:

```
-753774083758266900 -753774083758266900 -9223372036854776000
```

Perhaps the support for really large values (positive or negative) needs to be qualified.  Or, perhaps this is an artifact of how such numbers are printed in the output and has nothing to do with your problem.

As a note:  It does properly take the difference of these values, so this is perhaps just an output issue.